Using Unplugin-Auto-Import with Laravel/Vue3/Vite/InertiaJS+SSR/Pinia/Typescript stack?
I'm trying to get unplugin-auto-import to work within my Laravel/Vue3/Vite/InertiaJS+SSR/Typescript/Pinia project, and no matter what configuration I try, I seem to always get a ref is not defined error in the browser. Anyone get this Vite plugin to work?
My plugin config in vite.config.ts is literally bare bones at the moment:
...
AutoImport({
    imports:['vue']
})
...

and in my tsconfig.app.json file I have:
"include": [
    "auto-imports.d.ts",
    ...
],
...

I have tried dts: true, and vueTemplate: true, and neither seem to make a difference...

make sure your "auto-imports.d.ts" is generated properly and "include" contains a valid path to it

i appears to be generated properly, and it is generated in the root of my project, so I've just listed it as such above

what IDE? vscode?
